# CQRS architecture - How many databases use for reading and writing queries?

Tags: database-design, architecture, cqrs

I was reading an article about CQRS(Command Query Responsibility Segregation) architecture implementation but some articles showed a single database used for reading and writing queries and some articles showed two databases one for reading and another for write.

[Two database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtQi.png)

[Single databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDxP0.png)

So by referring above images exactly how many databases use while implementing CQRS architecture single or two?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please sya with text what the images are saying that can be said in text. Which is a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [CQRS](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/) is simply the creation of two objects where there was previously only one.  -- Greg Young

The CQRS pattern might be used with a single database; and also it might be used with more than one database (with background processes copying information from the "write" database to the "read" databases).

The short version: optimizing a database for queries is not the same as optimizing a database for writes.  For example, it might make sense to use an event store as your authoritative source of truth, but also cache that same information in a graph database that supports different query characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You can do CQRS with one database (e.g. having different tables for validating changes vs. external reads).

You can do CQRS with two databases.

You can do CQRS with *more than two* databases (conceivably, you could have a separate database for every query endpoint).

The key thing about CQRS is that gives you permission to optimize a write model for validating changes to state and to have external reads be against a read model as optimized for that particular read as you like.